# How to make print screen button act silently (not treated as key down)?

Tags: ubuntu, screenshot, print-screen

I'm trying to take a screenshot of this program while it is running.

When I press the print screen button, it raises a key down event which makes some elements in the program disappear.

I'm not able to get the right screenshot because the on pressing the button, things are changing on my screen.

A workaround?

I use Ubuntu 12.04.

**NOTE:** The program I'm trying to take a screenshot of, changes even in response to mouse clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try capturing a screenshot by `gimp`. It can either capture one window, or even the whole screen. In the menu, select `File` → `Create` → `Screenshot`.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. But like I said, clicking around will make changes in my running program. So, there must be a way to silently trigger a screenshot when a particular state is reached in my program. I feel clicking `File` and even switching window to `Gimp` will trigger changes.

Comment: You can set a timeout in `gimp`. It will wait the given amount of seconds.